# SOAP UI PRO_How to automate and send a single REST request for different Rest resource/method

Tags: rest, soapui

I am working on a project which requires me to send a single REST request and call different REST Resource/method for each call and store this response in a file. Can any one kindly help with this.

Comment: Could you be more specific on your answer?

Comment: For ex: I have 5 rest endpoints. I don't want to create 5 test cases in soap ui and send 5 different requests. I want to be able to send a single request which inturn calls the different rest endpoints(in my case 5 different) and then store all the request/response in a file. Let me know if you need more brief description. I can try to explain in detail.

Comment: Use a centralized endpoint: http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint